# Find Saturday before file date in bash

Tags: bash, date

I have a directory containing a large number of files to iterate and would like an efficient way to find the Saturday prior to the file's time of last modification.

Here are two examples. The first is just a simple file that was edited on

```
$ date -r file_1
Wed Jun 21 08:26:35 CDT 2017
$ date -d "$(date -r file_1 '+%F') - $(date -r file_1 '+%u') days - 1 days"
Sat Jun 17 00:00:00 CDT 2017
```

If it was modified on a Saturday, I want the previous Saturday.

```
$ date -r file_2
Sat Jun 17 00:00:00 CDT 2017
$ date -d "$(date -r file_2 '+%F') - $(date -r file_2 '+%u') days - 1 days"
Sat Jun 10 00:00:00 CDT 2017
```

As you can see, I have a method of doing this, but the process is computationally very long. It forces date to do natural english parsing and when you're doing this hundreds or thousands of times, it's very slow.

Comment: I have to admit I don't know all of the date routines available in bash and could write a C program using its date and time functions but I prefer to use utilities where available. Typically utilities are efficient but I don't want to use a screwdriver where a hammer would be more appropriate.  I will use the date routine unless advised otherwise. Thanks for your review.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What is "the file being modified"? What is this list of files? A text file containing file names? A PDF file? No file, just a directory containing files? You show some file in your question. What is that? What output would you expect to see from that file? We can't guess what you need, help us help you.

Comment: I've cleaned up the examples. They're functional but slow.

Comment: Thank you Oli for translating my example, yours is easier to understand and I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you're open to using Python, there are easy ways of doing this. See for example, [Finding the date of the next Saturday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16769902/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

1. About *100* times faster method, using `stat` to get the dates, then `date -f -` twice to do the math and formatting, with `/usr/bin/*` (*4852* files) as an example:

   ```
   stat -c %y /usr/bin/* | date -f - "+%F - %u days - 1 days" | date -f -
   ```

   Output is *4852* lines of various dates, all of which are previous Saturdays.
2. Slower:  Combining the two `date` subshells runs in about *33%* less
   time:

   ```
   date -r /bin/bash "+%F"  # print this only for reference
   date -d "$(date -r /bin/bash "+%F - %u days - 1 days")"
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   2017-05-16
   Sat May 13 00:00:00 EDT 2017
   ```

---

Benchmark for both, (the 2nd method in a `for` loop):

```
$ time -p stat -c %y /usr/bin/* | date -f - "+%F - %u days - 1 days" | \
       date -f - > /dev/null
real 0.19
user 0.14
sys 0.19
$ time -p for f in /usr/bin/* ; do \
       date -d "$(date -r "$f" "+%F - %u days - 1 days")" ; done > /dev/null
real 27.31
user 8.11
sys 14.93
```